# Got the error in SPFx installation "Yeoman Doctor - Running sanity checks on your system"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, spfx, npm, visual-studio-code

**Hi All,**

When I tried to installed the SPFx  "npm install -g yo" getting the issues.

Tried both "npm install -g yo@latest" and "npm rm -g yo", "npm install -g yo" but it didn't help.
Attached the Screenshot for regarding this issues advise me, if any wrong way i'm using.
before that I have installed many times SPFx in others systems.

Response appreciated.

Thanks in Advanced.

[image]

Comment: What is the version of node and npm? Also check the issues related to ` .npmrc` file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/591).

Comment: Yesterday update the node version,  Node-v  updated now. Thanks

Comment: Is it working now? Have you checked the `.npmrc` file?

Comment: Not Working, same issues are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added C:\Program Files\nodejs to your PATH environment variable ?

Follow the steps below :-

Search for the Environment Variables

Once you locate them Click on Edit Environment Variables.

Click "Environment Variables" .

In the "System Variables" option, search for "Path" and edit it by including C:\Program Files\nodejs.

Make sure it is separated from any other paths by a ;.

You may need to boot your system after this.

Comment: Thanks @Yash for response, I have checked it's available on the separate path.